# React how to deal with the uncertain number of states?

Tags: reactjs

For example let's say I have a component like this:

```
function MyComponent() {

const uncertainArray = [] // uncertain number of elements returning here
const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(true);

function clickEvent (){
  setIsShown(prevIsShown => !prevIsShown)
}

  return (
    uncertainArray.map(element => <div style={{display: isShown ? "block" : "none"}} onClick={clickEvent}>{element.name}</div>)
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

I want to control shown states of each element div ***individually***. But I don't know how many items will come from `uncertainArray` and I think it wouldn't be wise to declare state for each item there would be lots of states. How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: Make each element consume a functional component that handle its own shown/hidden state.

Comment: It seems like the best option here thanks @Terry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parent component **doesn't** need to know whether a given element is visible or not, put the `shown` state in the component showing a single element:

```
function Element({element}) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(true);
  if(!isShown) return null;
  // etc...
  return <div>{element.text}</div>;
}
```

If the parent component **does** need to know the visibility states, assuming each `element` has an unique ID you can use, keep the visibility states in a `Set`, `Map` or `object`; I'll use an `object` for simplicity:

```
function MyComponent() {
  // ...
  const [visibleIds, setVisibleIds] = React.useState({});
  // ...
  return uncertainArray.map(element => <div style={{display: visibleIds[element.id] ? "block" : "none"}} ...
}
```